# Sorting model objects in the View - call Model method in View or implement sort in Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By default when I call this:

```
<table>
  <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <tr>
```

The answers for a question are displayed in the order they were created.

What's the appropriate way to sort them according to their votes?

I'm not sure whether I need to call a method on the answers in the View or implement a sort function in the Controller or the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do it once, I'll do it in the view something like:

```
<% @questions.sort {|x,y| y.votes <=> x.votes }.each do |question| %>
  <p><%= @question.title %></p>       
<% end %>
```

And like cwninja, if there's anything more interesting than that I'll do the logic in the controller or a helper.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly a matter of style.

Personally:

- If it's a hard coded sort order, just stick it in the view.
- If it has some logic behind it (based on request params, needs pagination or anything else *interesting*) then stick the collection in an `@answers` variable.